# Android Application does not run in Eclipse Luna

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

My AVD is configured correctly, but when I click on the project to run it, this opens but is on a black screen with the word "Android", and nothing else happens...

Comment: Wait patiently for a (potentially long) while. Your emulator is booting up. That black screen with "Android" is the boot screen.

Comment: If you want the app to start faster, just connect your real phone and enable usb debugging. The app is started directly after you press the play icon. :)

Answer (score 0):

The AVD configuration: api level, ram size, cpu/abi ... must be compatible with the computer resources.

Maybe the AVD is just too slow because your computer don't has the enough memory/cpu for this AVD configuration, try a lower api level / ram size with ARM cpu instead Intel, or use a real device connected by USB with the AVD closed, and the app will start on the device.

This usually happens when running AVD on computers with limited resources.